# Conformity of $r^λ(\cos(λθ),\sin(λθ))$ for $λ∈\Bbb C$, $(r,θ)$ standard polar coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis

Welcome everybody :)

I have problems to solve the following task:

---

Let $\lambda∈\Bbb C$.

Define $$(r,\theta ) = r^λ (\cos(λ\theta ),\sin(λ\theta ))$$ Here $(r,\theta )$ are the standard polar coordinates in $\Bbb R^2 = \Bbb C$.

a) Show that $\phi$ is a conformal map on the slit plane $\{(r,\theta ) \mid r>0, -π<\theta <π\}$.

b) For which $λ$ does $\phi$ extend to a conformal map on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$?

c) For which $λ$ does $\phi$ extend to a conformal map on $\Bbb R^2$?

---

From my knowledge:
$f$ is a conformal map $:\iff$ $f$ is orientation- and angle-preserving

My approach/idea was the following:

$f$ is $C^1$ and Cauchy-Riemann DE holds ⇔ $f$ is holomorphic

$f$ holomorphic on $D$ and $f'(z₀) ≠ 0 \quad \forall z_0 \in D$ (Domain) $\iff$ $f$ is conformal.

But the main problem first:

If one has $\phi(r,\theta ) =  r^λ (\cos(λ\theta ),\sin(λ\theta ))$ how can I identify this with 
a function from lets say $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$?
Is it correct to say $\phi(r,\theta ) = r^λ (\cos(λ\theta ) + i \sin(λ\theta )$?

Normally I see it like this (correspondence of $\Bbb C$ with $\Bbb R^2$)

$f = u + iv \iff f = (u,v)$ with the standard basis ${(1,0),(0,i)}$ and $u,v$ functions from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. (real and imaginary part of $f$)

Furthermore, if my way of seeing this is correct, I would then show the CR-DE for polar-coordinates $u_\theta  = -r v_r ∧ v_\theta  = r u_r$ (where $u_r$ stands for the partial derivative)

Then I write out $r^λ$ as $\exp(λ\cdot Ln(r))$ and since I use the main-branch so 
$\exp(λ\cdot (\ln|r| + i arg(r) + 2kπi)) ⇒ \exp(λ\cdot \ln|r|) = \exp(λ\cdot \ln(r))$ correct?

Furthermore by setting $λ ≔ a + ib$ with $a,b ∈ ℝ$ one can simplifies
$$\cos(λ\theta ) = \cos((a+ib)\theta ) 
= \cos(a\theta ) \cosh(b\theta ) - \sin(a\theta ) i\cdot \sinh(b\theta ) \sin(λ\theta ) 
= \sin(a\theta ) \cosh(b\theta ) + i\cdot \cos(a\theta ) \sinh(b\theta )
then \cos(λ\theta ) + i\cdot \sin(λ\theta ) = [\cos(a\theta ) + i\cdot \sin(a\theta )] [\cosh(b\theta ) - \sinh(b\theta )] = \exp(ai\theta )\cdot \exp(-b\theta )$$

$⇒ r^λ\cdot (\cos(λ\theta ) + i \sin(λ\theta )) = \exp(a\cdot \ln(r)) \cdot \exp(ib\cdot \ln(r)) \cdot \exp(ai\theta ) \cdot \exp(-b\theta )$

and from this I get:

$u(r,\theta ) = \exp(a\cdot \ln(r) - b\theta ) \cdot \cos(b\cdot \ln(r) + a\theta )$
$v(r,\theta ) = \exp(a\cdot \ln(r) - b\theta ) \cdot \sin(b\cdot \ln(r) + a\theta )$

Then I can check if the CR-DE holds.
They are true.

Now my questions are:

i) Can I use the Jacobian of $ϕ$ (as a map $ℝ^2 → ℝ^2$) with the partial derivatives from the given u and v from above?

ii) Can I then say for checking the Jacobian of $ϕ$ (lets say J for this matrix)
$f' = J$ ?
Normaly $f'$ is a $ℂ-linear$ differntial from $ℂ → ℂ$ I know.

iii) Therefore I would check that $J(z₀) ≠ (0,0)$ for every point $z₀$ given in my domain? (here $ℂ⁻$)

iv) For the questions a,b,c I think the conformal mapping is destroyed if we extend $ℂ⁻$ to $ℝ^2$/{0} since $r^λ = \exp(λ\cdot \ln(r))$ but $\exp(λ)$ isn't an injective function for $λ∈ℂ$, right?
So I would say $λ$ has to be $λ∈ℤ$ to getting a unique power (required for conformal mapping).
Furthermore if the domain if $ℝ^2$ then by defining $0^0 ≔ 1$ I think $λ=0$ is the only way to get out of trouble?

v) The problem with the continuity is the main reason to restrict our domain, right?

vi) Do you understand $f$ conformal $\iff$ bijectiv $∧ f,f^{-1}$ are both holomorphic?

Does my teacher understand conformity (deduced from the task) as 
$f$ locally conformal $\iff$ $f$ angle- and orientation preserving?

Thank you very much for your help. We are 4 people working together and nobody has a clue how to solve this task. I hope my ideas are not entirely wrong :-}
This is a very cool site and I can use unifont directly from my keyboard, WOW :)

Greetings,

Poly

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Would you please edit your post to use MathJax rather than strange characters that don't even display in my browser?

Comment: I hope it works now for most of the users here. 
I enjoy tipping in unifont directly since it saves a lot of time. For the more sophisticated formulae one can use the commands, but for $∀ℂ×√⇔ΣΔ×Φ∃ℝ$ and so on its just cool to have a 6-layered keyboard layout.

Comment: do you mean Unicode? No amount of Unicode will make math look good, and your math is all screwy. Take it down to ASCII, please, use \Bbb R^2 for $\Bbb R^2$, use \sin for $\sin$, \iff for $\iff$, \sqrt{foo} for $\sqrt{foo}$, etc.

Comment: I dont know what you mean. On my machine it displays correctly, mb some spacing is not correct or the length of the symbol is not adequate for $⇔$ and longer formulae with many $=$ are a bit annoying.

Comment: hey thx dfeuer
I will check if it looks too annoying on other machines. But you have to remember to the good old times were formuale have been handwritten.
Anyway the content is important and I'm here to learn (and I'm inclined to learn also about the typing :-} )

Comment: Just take my word for it: Donald Knuth knew what he was doing when he designed $\TeX$'s mathematical language, upon which Mathjax is based. There's a reason it's still the industry standard after a few decades. Unicode was designed for natural languages, not for mathematics.

Comment: Make sure you include some smarphones/tablets in your testing, and that you look at both the output and the source (when editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I'm answering this assuming that we're talking about the requirement that a function is locally conformal, without the requirement that the function is globally injective. I believe this what the question is asking, otherwise the conclusion in part a) would be false...*

Functions defined as in the problem statement have always confused me, because it's not always clear (at least to me) whether the mapping is
\begin{eqnarray}
&\text{1)}&r + i \theta \mapsto r^\lambda e^{i \lambda \theta} \hspace{1cm} \\
\text{or}  &\text{2)}&r e^{i \theta}  \mapsto r^\lambda e^{i \lambda \theta} \hspace{1cm}
\end{eqnarray}

I'd like to think the author of the question meant 2), which is the same as the rectilinear mapping $z = r e^{i \theta} \mapsto r^\lambda e^{i \lambda \theta} = z^{\lambda}$, in other words
$$f(z) = z^{\lambda} = e^{\lambda \text{log}(z)}$$

This representation shows that requirement a) in the problem is met, because the split plane is simply connected and does not contain $z = 0$, so there's an analytic branch of $\text{log}(z)$ there. You can check that by the Chain Rule, $f'(z) = \lambda z^{\lambda - 1}$ (when $\lambda \ne 0$). $f'(z) \ne 0$ where it's defined, so the map is *locally* conformal.

To answer part b), we need to find $\lambda$ such that the branch of log$(z)$ used to define $f(z)$ does not affect the value of $f(z)$. For $\lambda$ like this, then $f(z)$ is well-defined on the whole punctured plane.

To do this, write $e^{\lambda \text{log}(z)} = e^{\lambda ( \text{log}(z) + 2\pi i)}$. We get equality precisely when $e^{\lambda 2 \pi i}$ = 1, so $\lambda$ is any integer.

To answer part c) notice that a $\lambda$ that satisfies part c) must also satisfy part b), so $\lambda$ is necessarily an integer. The additional requirement is that $f(z)$ be conformal at $z = 0$. This obviously never happens for $\lambda \lt 0$, since $f(z)$ is not defined at $z = 0$ in this case. But when $\lambda$ is a *strictly positive* integer, then $f'(0) = 0$, so $f$ is not conformal at the origin (it's $\lambda$-to-one). The only possibility is $\lambda = 0$, which gives $f(z) = 1$ the constant function, which isn't conformal.

Comment: Hey bryanj,

Many thanks for your prompt response!
I appreciate that you also understand the task in the way I did.
So then more formally this $ϕ(r,θ)$ becomes $f(z) = z^λ$ with $z = re^{iθ}$.

But there are still a few questions left (apart from the original ones which I would like to get answered shortly if possible):

My idea was using CR-DGL in polar-coordinates to show that $f'(z) = e^{-iθ} (u_r + iv_r)$ since I wasn't sure that, like you did, $f'(z) = λz^{λ-1}$ since $λ∈ℂ$.

So I would appreciate if you could add a few more details on the thinking about local conformity.
Furthermore

Comment: - I'm not really sure about your argumentation. 
I don't think there exist a branch of $log(z)$ on $ℂ*$.
What about the argumentation for part c), mb add few details that would help me.

And in general I would like to have a statement about my questions i) to v), a short answer is absolutely ok since I want to check how you see this problem with how $λ$ has to be adjusted to save local conformity.

Thank you in advance
RedPen

Comment: For part b), I'm not claiming that there's a continuous branch of $\log(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}_*$, but rather that for certain $\lambda$, you get the same value for $f(z)$ *no matter which branch of $\log(z)$ you choose*. I don't have any thoughts right now about i) to v).

Comment: Someone else has a clue?
It is important since I need a well-argued, complete solution for the exam.

Comment: I think your solution is fine, except part c) 
I will accept the solution anyhow, thank you again for your effort!
Red Pencil